# remove values on the basis of values in another column

Tags: r

i have two columns in data frame both have values like one have total score and one have expected score.i want to ignore the condition in tota_score is NA. now i want to values from expected score columns where expected score is greater that total score.

```
 df <- data.frame(tota_score=c(4.5,12.2,4.6,9.2,12.2,NA,4.5,12.2,4.6,9.2,12.2,36.4),
                   expected_score=c(4.5,12.1,NA,10,12.2,36.4,5,12.5,NA,9.2,16,NA),
                   Region1=c("All region",NA,NA,"All region","All region",NA,"All region",NA,NA,"All region","All region",NA),
                   Region2=c("EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST",NA,"EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST","EAST",NA),
                   Region3=c("West",NA,"West","West","West","West","West",NA,"West","West","West","West"))
df %>%
    mutate(expected_score = ifelse(!is.na(expected_score) > !is.na(tota_score), 
                                   NA, expected_score))
```

required output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what `!is.na(expected_score)` returns will help sort out why the condition isn't working as you expect.

```r
!is.na(NA)
#> [1] FALSE

!is.na(5)
#> [1] TRUE

!is.na(5) > !is.na(NA)
#> [1] TRUE

!is.na(NA) > !is.na(5)
#> [1] TRUE
```

You want to compare the values for `expected_score` and `tota_score` and not whether they are `NA`. You could check whether a value is not `NA` and then nest a conditional statement for when that is true. Here's an alternative way to write this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(expected_score = if_else(expected_score > tota_score,
                                  NA,
                                  expected_score,
                                  missing = expected_score))
#>    tota_score expected_score    Region1 Region2 Region3
#> 1         4.5            4.5 All region    EAST    West
#> 2        12.2           12.1       <NA>    EAST    <NA>
#> 3         4.6             NA       <NA>    EAST    West
#> 4         9.2             NA All region    EAST    West
#> 5        12.2           12.2 All region    EAST    West
#> 6          NA           36.4       <NA>    <NA>    West
#> 7         4.5             NA All region    EAST    West
#> 8        12.2             NA       <NA>    EAST    <NA>
#> 9         4.6             NA       <NA>    EAST    West
#> 10        9.2            9.2 All region    EAST    West
#> 11       12.2             NA All region    EAST    West
#> 12       36.4             NA       <NA>    <NA>    West
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>